# how can I upload image that converted to base64 using alamofire?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode10

I'm using Alamofire to manage the network in my app 
the API that I'm using to upload the image to the server need two parameters which is image name and the image data ( base 64 string )
I know how to convert image to base64 using this code

```
    class func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    return imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
}
```

but I don't know how to get the image name ?!
second if I got the image name how to upload the image to the server can anyone explain the Alamofire code that upload the image ?

this is my API

Web Method :

### https://serverName/AddPhoto

### Paramaters

{
"FileName":"Hydrangeas.jpg",
"ImageData":"base64string"
}

notes:
FileName : the select file name of Photo
ImageData : Base 64 String represent Imge Bytes

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

step 01 :

import Photos library in top

```
import Photos
```

get your image using UIImagePickerController() like this

```
var base64Image: String?
var fileName: String?
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary

    }
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

        if let asset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {
                if let fileName = (asset.value(forKey: "filename")) as? String {
                    self.fileName = fileName
                }
            }


         base64Image = convertImageToBase64(image: image)

        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {
        let imageData = image.pngData()!
        return imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
    }
```

Step 02:
set base64Image in your param like this

```
{ "FileName":"\(fileName)", "ImageData":"\(base64Image)" }
```

Comment: but i need to upload image as jpg how can i do that ?

Comment: trying your code but red error appear  - > Use of undeclared type 'PHAsset'

Comment: import UIKit below add
import Photos

Comment: check this code working my project, clean build your project

Comment: while i'm building the project i got this error - > Type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'phAsset'

Comment: what is your swift version can you tell me